# Python - Check if uploaded CSV has header without saving it?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there a way to check if a csv uploaded via an POST request has a header without having to actually save the csv?

Also if anyone has any suggestions for making the way I'm uploading the csv file, they are free to make suggestions.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
    uploaded_file_name = uploaded_file.name

    if len(uploaded_file) != 0:
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
            id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            df.to_csv(f'{TRAIN_FILES}/{id}.csv', index=False)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'msg': str(e)}, status=500)

        return JsonResponse({'msg': id}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'msg': 'File is empty'}, status=500)
```

So the reason I'm reading it using pandas is cause I use pandas to read it and project it to a table later. I'm not using pandas purely just to validate it's a valid CSV.

So along with making sure that uploaded_file has a header, it needs:

- Make sure it's not an empty csv
- Make sure it is a csv
- Make sure it's pandas readable

If it doesn't meet any of the above requirements it should return a response with the message of the error.

What's a good way to check all of this? I looked into csv.sniffer but I think you actually need to have the csv saved to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with CSV files is that I don't think you can tell if the file has a header row, unless you know something about the contents.  If you know the name of the first column, you could see if that name is in row 0.  If you know that the 2nd column is supposed to be an integer you could see if the value of row 0 col 1 is string or int.

```
name,age,color
julian,3,red
raja,2,purple
zendai,4,green
```

There is really nothing special about the header row, except that in the 2nd column, it has a string "age" instead of an integer.